# Finding a button in Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to find this specific button. I've tried using find button in capybara to do this but I'm unable to.

```
find(:button, 'Open Cow menu').click
```

HTML Tag

```
<button class="cd-icon-button cd-button cd-irx-cyan-theme" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="Open Cow menu" ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="menu_container_1">
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
```

I'm sure there is a easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`Open Cow menu`* is the value of the ***aria-label*** attribute.

So you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
find('button[aria-label=Open Cow menu]').click
```

or

```
find('button[aria-label="Open Cow menu"]').click
```